# Electric field with $\nabla \times \vec{E} = 0$ and $\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = 0$ outside of a conductor circulates a constant electric current

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, mathematical-physics, electromagnetism

> Q: suppose that I know that outside of some conductor circulates a constant electric current , I have $\nabla \times \vec{E} = 0$ and $\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = 0$. How do I prove that $\vec{E} = 0 $ outside of the conductor.

**More details:**

The conductor is:  **An ideal solenoid is an infinite cylindric conductor with a cylindric
cavity along the same axis. On the surface of the conductor circulates a
constant electric current in the direction perpendicular to its axis. Show that the electromagnetic field created by the current vanishes outside the conductor and the cavity**

I proved that the magnetic field $\vec{B} = 0$  outside of the conductor and I want to prove that the electric field $\vec{E}$ is also zero outside. With Faraday's law, I have $\nabla \times \vec{E} = rot(\vec{E}) = curl(\vec{E}) = 0$.
With Gauss's law I have $\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = div(\vec{E}) = 0$

How with that information, I can prove that $\vec{E} = 0$ outside of the ideal solenoid.

Thanks!!

Comment: You need to specify in what region those functions are zero. Secondly, $\nabla \times \vec{E} \approx 0 $ , it's never totally equal to zero because this is not an electrostatic case

Comment: @Buraian this is the question I have:
"An ideal solenoid is an infinite cylindric conductor with a cylindric
cavity along the same axis. On the surface of the conductor circulates a
constant electric current in the direction perpendicular to its axis. Show
that the electromagnetic field created by the current vanishes outside the
conductor and the cavity."

Comment: How did you prove that B is zero outside? It will add to the question if you show your work

Comment: @Buraian it is a "little bit" long but those are the stages:
(1)  $\vec{B}$ has only $\hat{z}$ component.
(2) $\vec{B}$ is  tranlation-z constant and rotation-constant.
(3) $\vec{B}$ is constant.
(4) at$ \infty $ $\vec{B} = 0$.
so it is 0

Comment: You can't, you also need to specify the charge density, which may be independant of the current. The commonly assumed case would be that $\rho=0$, in which case $E=0$.  It you instead assume that $\rho\neq 0$ is uniform over the conductur sheet, you will get no field inside, and a radial field propotional to $\rho/r$.